# how to get rid of 'zombie' channels

Tags: django-channels

In Django Channels documentation ([here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#single-channels)) there is the following example

```py
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        # Make a database row with our channel name
        Clients.objects.create(channel_name=self.channel_name)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Note that in some rare cases (power loss, etc) disconnect may fail
        # to run; this naive example would leave zombie channel names around.
        Clients.objects.filter(channel_name=self.channel_name).delete()
```

So I am worried about this note:

> Note that in some rare cases (power loss, etc) disconnect may fail
> # to run; this naive example would leave zombie channel names around.

What can be done about it? Is there a safe way to monitor whether the client is still connected, and if he doesn't delete his record from db?

Comment: Those are rare cases as mentioned but if you want to take care of such cases, one way could be to clear all channel data from the channel layer on server start. In this way, if power went out and the server went offline then on coming back online, it will delete all "zombie" channel names before new connections come in

Comment: Thanks! Does it make sense and feasible  to loop over the channel names and check that the clients are still active?

Comment: No need to loop over. As far as you are using a single server instance then if the server went offline, all clients definitely disconnected. So as the server starts up again, you can delete all channel names before it starts accepting new connections. Else, there is no other way of actually knowing that they are connected even if you are to loop through the names